# How to make the settings of custom 403 page and url rewriting coexist?

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, http-status-code-404, http-status-code-403

In my .htaccess file, I have the settings for rewriting urls such as `http://www.myownwebsite.com/about.php` to `http://www.myownwebsite.com/about/`.

And I also have the settings for custom error 403 and 404 pages.

The issue I'm encountering is that, when I'm testing accessing a folder directly, for example, `http://www.myownwebsite.com/css/`, instead of seeing the custom 403 page, I'm seeing the custom 404 page. I guess that's because the settings of url rewriting is overwriting the setting of custom 403 page.

Here is the related code in my .htaccess file:

```
ErrorDocument 403 /403.php
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /$1/$2.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before adding `.php` to your URIs make sure corresponding `.php` file exists.

Better to keep redirect rule before other rules.

Have it like this:

```
Options -MultiViews -Indexes
ErrorDocument 403 /403.php
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1/$2.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /$1/$2.php [L]
```

Comment: I see. Your advice is much appreciated. I will put redirect rule before other rules.